# How to detect which week and month are clicked on a JCalendar?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a Java GUI calendar application using the JCalendar Library, and I want to be able to detect which week of which month was clicked by the user so I can then open a new JFrame.

This is the code I have right now, I just sysouted the DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH because I wanted to see if it was working, but all I get are singular int values, which are not useful. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The JCalendar Library I'm using is https://toedter.com/jcalendar/.

```
    JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar();
    calendar.setBounds(416, 70, 304, 243);
    frame.getContentPane().add(calendar);
    calendar.addPropertyChangeListener("calendar", new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            final Calendar c = (Calendar) e.getNewValue();   
            System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH));   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which JCalendar library are you using?

Comment: @MadProgrammer https://toedter.com/jcalendar/